# How do I output a command that acts on multiple files, to multiple files?

Tags: files, filenames

I am attempting to use the objdump command to disassemble all files in the current directory with the .o extension, and then put the output of this command for each .o file, into a .txt file with the same basename.

So as an example, let's suppose I have these three files in my directory:

`myfirstfile.o
someotherfile.o
finalfile.o`

My goal is to end up with three new additional files (each containing the output of the `objdump` command from the corresponding original .o file):

`myfirstfile.txt
someotherfile.txt
finalfile.txt`

This is what I have attempted, but it just puts says "ambiguous redirect":

`objdump -d --no-show-raw-insn *.o > *.txt`

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to run one command per file, so best is to use a loop.

With the `zsh` shell:

```
for f (./*.o) objdump -d --no-show-raw-insn $f > $f:r.txt
```

With the `bash` shell or any other POSIX shell (including `zsh`):

```
for f in ./*.o; do objdump -d --no-show-raw-insn "$f" > "${f%.o}.txt"; done
```

Beware that one will create an empty file called `*.txt` if there's no `.o` file (except in `zsh`).

Answer (score 0):

how about making a file called myobjdump.sh which is run as follows:

```
./myobjdump.sh `ls *.o`
```

and the script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

for ((i=1; i<=$#; i++)); do
  objdump -d --no-show-raw-insn $i > `basename $i .o`.txt
done
```

**Edit**

```
#!/bin/bash

for n in $@; do
  objdump -d --no-show-raw-insn $n > `basename $n .o`.txt
done
```

Comment: I tried running this, and it seems to be assuming that the files are named 1, 2, 3, etc, rather than using the actual basenames of the files.

Comment: that's odd. I get it too. but if I do echo `basename $i .o`.txt  alone, that works

Comment: Why `./myobjdump.sh \`ls *.o\`` and not `./myobjdump.sh *.o`?

Comment: @xenoid that way does seem more elegant in retrospect. In that case I may as  well put ./*.o in the for loop and not use any input to the script. I won't change my answer though, because someone else already did that